# iterative machine learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithm, iteration

I need a machine learning algorithm which takes some training samples of form (x,y),
and compute approximate function f:X->Y such that the error is minimum. error is defined as the difference b/n y and f(x).

But this learning algorithm must be a iterative one,and As the no.of iterations increases, the error must be decreased.

Any example would be helpful.

Comment: This basically describes every machine learning algorithm... Maybe try a neural network?

Comment: Actually here i mean by iterations is analog with time,i.e., as the learning algorithm is given more computational time , the error is more decreased.

Comment: Here i don't mean that in the iterations new training data is given.

Comment: "I need a machine learning algorithm which takes some training samples of form (x,y), and compute approximate function f:X->Y such that the error is minimum." Sounds to me like you want a very basic regression analysis, not machine learning to solve your particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neural network is one algorithm that have two features: 
1. It can train iterativly on new data
2. It can train on same data iterativly, so error is decreased with each iteration. (back propagation learning)

Answer (score 0):

1. (stochastic) gradient boosting,
2. AdaBoost,

...and any boosting algorithm generally, because boosting process improves classifier iteratively.